# Unit test angular directive which checks the existence of a css class then remove it

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-directive

I am currently working on a generic list solution which's appearance can be changed with an attribute directive from vertical to horizontal. It simply removes a css class and adds a new one.

In a private function of the directive which is called in afterViewInit I am expecting an element existence and based on the result I might throw an error.

To unit test my directive I created a sample test component:

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <app-list horizontal-list>
            <app-list-item title="First item"></app-list-item>
            <app-list-item title="Second item"></app-list-item>
            <app-list-item title="Third item"></app-list-item>
        </app-list> 
    `
})
```

And my directive code snippet is here:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[horizontal-list]'
})
export class SampleDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  sampleList: Element;

  constructor(private readonly elementRef: ElementRef, private readonly renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.checkDOMPrecondition();

    this.switchToVerticalToHorizontal();
  }

  private checkDOMPrecondition(): void {
    this.sampleList = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.sample-list-vertical');

    if (!(!!sampleList)) {
      throw new Error('Required dom element is missing');
    }
  }

  private switchToVerticalToHorizontal(): void {
    this.renderer.removeClass(this.sampleList, 'sample-list-vertical');
    this.renderer.addClass(this.tabList, 'sample-list-horizontal');
  }
}
```

If I run my test, because of the way the component is created (with the directive) the css class is already removed. So if I call component.afterViewInit to test the throw like that:

```
expect(() => component.afterViewInit()).toThrowError('Required dom element is missing');
```

will throw error automatically, because it is running after test component creation where we already removed the expected css class.

Furthermore if I want to create a unit test scenario where it does not throw error I have no clue how to do that.

Do you guys have solution for my problem? Hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I found only one solution to this problem. I created stub component for appListItem component which does not have the expected style. Added this stub component to a separated TestBed configureTestingModule object I was able to test this behavior.